# How to publish RDS error logs to CloudWatch using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to add some text to my CloudFormation code that will cause my Aurora RDS error logs to be published to CloudWatch.  Does anybody know how to do it?

Here's a [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.CloudWatch.html) to the documentation, where they only address doing it in the AWS Console, the CLI and the SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS CloudFormation added a new property to the *AWS::RDS::DBInstance* resource that can be used to achieve what you are looking for. The new property is called *EnableCloudwatchLogsExports*, More information can be found in the following link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-enablecloudwatchlogsexports

Answer (score 1):

you need to use an AWS CloudFormation Custom Resource (e.g. Lambda function) and leverage the SDK of your choice to invoke the ModifyDbInstance API to configure CloudWatch Logs Export.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBInstance.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.